# How to call Google Drive API from Cloud Function for Firebase on behalf of a user?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-drive-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I want to interact with the Google's [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api) from a Cloud Function for Firebase. For authentication / authorization, I am currently relying on `getClient`, which I believe uses the Service Account exposed in the Cloud Function environment:

```js
import { google } from 'googleapis';

// Within the Cloud Function body:
const auth = await google.auth.getClient({
  scopes: [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
  ],
});
const driveAPI = google.drive({ version: 'v3', auth });

// read files, create file etc. using `driveAPI`...
```

The above approach works, as long as target directories / files list the email address of the service account as an editor.

However, I'd like to interact with the Drive API *on behalf of another user* (which I control), so that this user becomes (for example) the owner of files being created. How can I achieve this?

Comment: in order to do it on behalf of another user your going to have to configure domain wide delegation to the service account, via google workspace.

Comment: @DaImTo Thank you for that pointer! Based on this suggestion, I set up domain-wide delegation in the Google Workspaces Admin UI for the Service Account in question. How would I define the email address to impersonate in `getClient`, though?

Comment: client.subject = user;  <-- should work   Are you using javascript or nodejs?

Comment: I am using the Google APIs Node.js Client within Cloud Functions for Firebase. My code is written in TypeScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to achieve calling the Drive API on behalf of another user thanks to the suggestions made by @DalmTo.

The first step is to configure [domain-wide delegation of authority in Google Workspace](https://support.google.com/a/answer/162106?product_name=UnuFlow&hl=en&visit_id=638029885719705437-953591952&rd=1&src=supportwidget0&hl=en) for the default AppEngine Service Account.

Next, the code in my question can be extended to receive a `subject` with the email of the user to impersonate via the `clientOptions`:

```js
import { google } from 'googleapis';

// Within the Cloud Function body:
const auth = await google.auth.getClient({
  scopes: [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
  ],
  clientOptions: {
    subject: 'email@to.impersonate',
  },
  keyFile: './serviceAccountKey.json',
});
const driveAPI = google.drive({ version: 'v3', auth });

// read files, create file etc. using `driveAPI`...
```

Now, the truly odd thing is that this **only works** when *also* passing the service account key via the `keyFile` option in addition. I.e., relying on the key being automatically populated (as it is in Cloud Functions for Firebase) does NOT work when also trying to impersonate a request. There are [ongoing discussions](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs/issues/916) of this bug on GitHub, specifically see [this comment](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs/issues/916#issuecomment-1080595410).

---

To make domain-wide delegation work **without having to provide the `keyFile` option** (which will likely require you to manage the sensitive key file in some way), another option is to sign a JWT and use it to obtain an Oauth token. The approach is [outlined by Google](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/best-practices-for-managing-service-account-keys#domain-wide-delegation), and I found [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60506185/1023827) providing a code-example very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

To set the user you want to deligate as in your code just add a subject to the client, with user being the email of the user on your workspace domain.

```
const client = await auth.getClient();
client.subject = user;
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried setting `client.subject` to the email address of the user to impersonate, but it has no effect: The file created with the client is still owned by the service account's email address. I am using TypeScript and the type checker complaints when setting `client.subject`, as field `subject` does not exist on any of the types returned by `google.auth.getClient`. Maybe I cannot use `getClient` for this use-case?

Comment: You got me it should work.  you could just do a permissions insert to get around it though.   But tbh you shouldnt have to.

Comment: Not having any success so far. I also tried passing the subject as part of the options for `getClient` like so: `google.auth.getClient({ clientOptions: { subject: 'example@mail.com', }, ...});`. But the file created still lists the original service account.

Comment: should be something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/73034970/1841839  sorry i dont have the power of nodejs right now so i cant test it.

Comment: Thank you for your pointers! The code you linked does not error, but it does also not lead to the `user` email being set instead of the service account one. Can it be that configuring changes to domain-wide delegation take time to propagate? I just set things up ±1 hour ago.